# Moving from bs-options in angularstrap to select in vanilla

Tags: angularjs

This is part of my page

```
<div ng-controller="dtbCtrl" class="container">
  <div class="thumbnail"><img ng-src="{{pic + selectedPitch + selectedWood}}" class="img-responsive">
    <div class="caption">
      <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
        <label class="hidden-xs">Registro: </label>
        <button type="button" ng-model="selectedPitch" bs-options="pitch.value as pitch.label for pitch in pitches" bs-select="" animation="am-flip-x" data-placement="right-top" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Seleziona <span class="caret"></span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
        <label class="hidden-xs">Legno: </label>
        <button type="button" ng-model="selectedWood" bs-options="wood.value as wood.label for wood in woods" bs-select="" animation="am-flip-x" data-placement="left-top" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Seleziona <span class="caret"></span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this from app.js

```
app.controller('dtbCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.selectedPitch = 'Compara';
  $scope.selectedWood = 'Compara';
  $scope.pitches = [
    {
      value: 'compara',
      label: 'Compara'
    }, {
      value: 'grave',
      label: 'Grave'
    }, {
      value: 'medio',
      label: 'Medio'
    }, {
      value: 'Acuto',
      label: 'Acuto'
    }
  ];
  $scope.woods = [
    {
      value: 'compara',
      label: 'Compara'
    }, {
      value: 'teak',
      label: 'Teak'
    }, {
      value: 'padouk',
      label: 'Padouk'
    }
  ];
  $scope.pic = 'http://www.placehold.it/1618x1000?text=';
});
```

Everything works fine with angular-strap, but without it, moving to vanilla (well, just angular), it doesn't.

```
<select ng-options="pitch.label for pitch in pitches" ng-model="{{selectedPitch}}"></select>
```

What am I doing wrong? Why do I get no options in the select form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `ng-model="selectedPitch"` and not `ng-model="{{selectedPitch}}"`.

Comment: Well, yes, I'm an idiot :D tried too many solutions, and for frustation tried stupid things without reverting them